# In an expression of wish, desires, containing 'If' and 'had', should 'would have' necessarily come after that or simply 'would' would do fine?

Tags: would

Are both of these correct?

1. "If I had to choose one, I would have to say it's red that I prefer the most among all the colours."
2. "If I had to choose one, I would say it's red that I prefer the most among all the colours."

Comment: If I had a boat, I'd go out on the ocean  
— Lyle Lovett, _If I Had a Boat_

Comment: And if I had a pony, I’d ride him on my boat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. The first has more of a obligated tone to it, because of the 'have to', and the second simply talks about what action you would take, but both mean the same thing.